# How to fix "No generic element handlers found for namepsace" error in case using custom genericElement?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to adapted the [example](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/genericelement/index.htm) of jasper reports to customized a generic element with a HTML handler to an Example with a PDF handler. But I got all the time the same error message, when trying to run the

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No generic element handlers found for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/customPDFexpoter.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.GenericElementHandlerEnviroment.getElementHandler(GenericElementHandlerEnviroment.java:112)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportGenericElement(JRPdfExporter.java:4136)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1290)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1210)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1074)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:691)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.actions.export.AExportAction.exportWithProgress(AExportAction.java:223)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.actions.export.AExportAction.doPreview(AExportAction.java:347)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.actions.export.AExportAction$3.run(AExportAction.java:191)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Also I've followed this [example](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/801396/embedding-print-page-control-pdf) how to embedd a controller to a PDF, without success. Also there the namespace can't be found. Did I miss something in the project configuration?

**here is my JRXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.14.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.14.0-2ab0d8625be255bf609c78e1181801213e51db8f  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c685fd77-7e9f-4762-9a4a-422d1c15aed0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="500" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <genericElement>
                <reportElement x="94" y="93" width="236" height="107" uuid="0dbdbc2d-cead-47eb-8605-e18cc325259a"/>
                <genericElementType namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/customPDFexpoter" name="print"/>
            </genericElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**My jasperreports_extension.properties** (inside src-Folder)

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.jr.statistics=net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.jr.statistics.spring.beans.resource=com/test/beans.xml
```

**The beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
<bean id="pdfExportHandlerBundle" 
        class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.DefaultElementHandlerBundle">
    <property name="namespace" value="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/customPDFexpoter"/>
    <property name="elementHandlers">
        <map>
            <entry key="print">
                <map>
                    <entry key="net.sf.jasperreports.pdf">
                        <ref bean="basePdfExportHandler"/>
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="basePdfExportHandler" class="com.test.TestPDFHandler"
        abstract="true">
</bean>
```

**The Java-File (src/com/test)**

```
package com.test;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRGenericPrintElement;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.GenericElementHandler;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.GenericElementHandlerBundle;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.GenericElementPdfHandler;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterContext;
import net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsRegistry;
import net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsRegistryFactory;
import net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.SingletonExtensionRegistry;

import com.lowagie.text.Chunk;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfAction;

public class TestPDFHandler implements GenericElementPdfHandler {

@Override
public boolean toExport(JRGenericPrintElement element) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void exportElement(JRPdfExporterContext exporterContext,
        JRGenericPrintElement element) {
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("print me");
    chunk.setAction(PdfAction.javaScript("this.print(null,this.pageNum,this.pageNum)", exporterContext.getPdfWriter()));
    phrase.add(chunk);

    ColumnText colText = new ColumnText(exporterContext.getPdfWriter().getDirectContent());
    colText.setSimpleColumn(phrase, 
            element.getX(), 
            exporterContext.getExportedReport().getPageHeight() - element.getY(),
            element.getX() + element.getWidth(), 
            exporterContext.getExportedReport().getPageHeight() - element.getY() - element.getHeight(), 
            0, 
            Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

    try {
        colText.go();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw new JRRuntimeException(e);
    }

}
/*
@Override
public String getNamespace() {
    return "helloWorld";
}

@Override
public GenericElementHandler getHandler(String elementName, String exporterKey) {
    if (elementName.equals("print") && exporterKey.equals(JRPdfExporter.PDF_EXPORTER_KEY)) {
        return this;
    }
    
    return null;
}

@Override
public ExtensionsRegistry createRegistry(String registryId, JRPropertiesMap properties) {
    return new SingletonExtensionRegistry<GenericElementHandlerBundle>(GenericElementHandlerBundle.class, this);
}*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register it as a factory in `jasperreports_extension.properties` add

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.me=com.test.TestPDFHandler
```

When this is done, then you need to implement the interface that are missing in your `TestPDFHandler` and `getNamespace()` needs to correspond with the namespace that you have given to the `genericElementType`*

```
public class TestPDFHandler implements GenericElementPdfHandler, GenericElementHandlerBundle, ExtensionsRegistryFactory {

    @Override
    public boolean toExport(JRGenericPrintElement element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void exportElement(JRPdfExporterContext exporterContext,
            JRGenericPrintElement element) {
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("print me");
        chunk.setAction(PdfAction.javaScript("this.print(null,this.pageNum,this.pageNum)", exporterContext.getPdfWriter()));
        phrase.add(chunk);

        ColumnText colText = new ColumnText(exporterContext.getPdfWriter().getDirectContent());
        colText.setSimpleColumn(phrase,
                element.getX(),
                exporterContext.getExportedReport().getPageHeight() - element.getY(),
                element.getX() + element.getWidth(),
                exporterContext.getExportedReport().getPageHeight() - element.getY() - element.getHeight(),
                0,
                Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        try {
            colText.go();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new JRRuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/customPDFexpoter";
    }

    @Override
    public GenericElementHandler getHandler(String elementName, String exporterKey) {
        if (elementName.equals("print") && exporterKey.equals(JRPdfExporter.PDF_EXPORTER_KEY)) {
            return this;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionsRegistry createRegistry(String registryId, JRPropertiesMap properties) {
        return new SingletonExtensionRegistry<GenericElementHandlerBundle>(GenericElementHandlerBundle.class, this);
    }
}
```

<sub>*You can indicate whatever namespace, I would not use `http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/customPDFexpoter` since it's not my domain but to follow your code it is used in example below</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the replay. but I get still the sam eerror. Did I have to configure something more inside the Project?

Comment: @carsten No nothing more (I tested), check that your factory registration work, for example by setting an incorrect class name net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.me=com.test.TestPDFHandlerTestError, jasper should throw error missing class.

Comment: Do note that your beans settings as indicated in question is not relevant to this problem

Comment: I guess the Project did not recordzied my jasperreports_extension.properties file. I've set a wrong Class name and still get the error. I've checked the Java Build path and it's point to my src folder. I have created a git Project feel free to have a look at it: https://github.com/Carsten64/my-jasper-report

Comment: @carsten [it works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cnzt8.png) for me, the difference that I have is that I had to add jar in classpath. I think some of the classes that you have in class-path already have a jasperreports_extension.properties that overrides yours (maybe in the server container or in some fonts-extensions)

Comment: I can see you are wokring with eclipse direktly. I am wokring with Jaspersoft Studio 6.14. Are there any bigger differences? I also Included JasperReports Library, Jaspersoft Server Library and JasperReports Library Dependencies.

Comment: Ahhhh I got it I had to delete the Jaspersoft Server Libray. now I get the same result. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Im SAM;

- Download .JAR  jasperreports-htmlcomponent-5.0.1.jar , and save in ANYFOLDER.
- With terminal o console typing cd ANYFOLDER
- exec on terminal

```
mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=jasperreports-htmlcomponent-5.0.1.jar \
-DgroupId=net.sf.jasperreports \
-DartifactId=jasperreports-htmlcomponent \
-Dversion=5.0.1 \
-Dpackaging=jar  \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

- GO TO PROJECT in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-htmlcomponent</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

- compile.
- Ready ...Enjoy.

Comment: Work only Maven >3.6.1

Comment: download JAR on http://maven.cantabria.es/artifactory/amap/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports-htmlcomponent/5.0.1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-html-component</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

adding dependency jasperreports-html-component helped me, but maven download broken file, if that's the case you can download directly from maven .rar